# read.csv skip lines until string found in first column

Tags: r, read.csv

I have 10 csv files that each have different numbers of lines to skip before the table starts with the data. Each table that I want to read has the same column name of 'Date Time' in the first column.

I'm reading in the data as a forloop and adding each data frame to a list. Is there a way to read in each dataframe and skip lines until the string 'Date Time' is detected and then read the table from that line?

##### Current Code

```
# Read troll data in
trollFiles <- list.files(pattern="_2019.csv")

dataList <- list()
baroList <- list()

for (var in trollFiles) {
  filepath <- file.path(paste(var))
  fileName <- (substr(var, 1,nchar(var)-4))
  file <- read.csv(filepath, sep="", header=T, col.names=c('DateTime', 'Pressure', 'Temperature'), check.names=FALSE, skip=25)
  file$Pressure <- as.numeric(file$Pressure)
  file$Temperature <- as.numeric(file$Temperature)
  ifelse(fileName == 'baro_2019', baroList[[fileName]] <- file,  dataList[[fileName]] <- file)  # save baro separately 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table::fread`, where we can specify first column name with `skip`:

```
library(data.table)

fread("
sometext
ignore
c1,c2,c3
11,22,33
44,55,66", 
      skip = "c1")
#   c1 c2 c3
#1: 11 22 33
#2: 44 55 66
```